# Amazon connect URL not opens the softphone it directly open the home tab of amazon connect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I have embeded the amazon connect ccp in my angular project. i have configured it from the amazon connect stream API. when i put my credentials it redirect me to the home tab I want to open the softphone tab directly. below are my configuration for amazon connect.

```
ccpUrl:environment.amazoneConnecDomain+environment.amazonConnecUrl,
loginPopup:false,
softphone: {
allowFramedSoftphone: true,
disableRingtone: false,
> >     },
loginOptions: this.getLoginOption(),
region: 'eu-central-1',
region: 'ap-southeast-2',

ccpAckTimeout: 5000, //optional, defaults to 3000 (ms)
ccpSynTimeout: 1000, //optional, defaults to 1000 (ms)
ccpLoadTimeout: 100000, //optional, defaults to 5000 (ms)
```

I expect to open the Amazone connect ccp softphone directly.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. Make sure to add your app url to list of Approved Origins in Connect. If you work locally, add local host with the correct schema and port number, for example ‘http://localhost:3000’.

Answer (score 0):

use `` const ccpURL = `https://${instanceAlias}.my.connect.aws/ccp-v2# `` instead of `https://${instanceAlias}.my.connect.aws/login`